# How to send a JSON to PHP and decode?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying send a JSON to PHP. In PHP Script I'm trying get this JSON using $_POST but doesn't works, when I try use `echo $json` does not display value. To test if PHP Script is works I'm using RESTClient of Mozilla Firefox.

How could I send a JSON to PHP using $_POST ?

**JSON**

```
{
"jsondata":{
    "nome":"my name"
}}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$jsondata = $_POST['jsondata'];
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
print_r($data);

?>
```

**Exception**

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: jsondata in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/TelefonesUteis/ws/add_estado.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

Line 6 have->`$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);`

[image]

Comment: That is not valid JSON - you have a `}` missing.

Comment: Can you please share the entire code? Also json seems to be invalid

Comment: Are you aware that [`json_decode` will return `NULL` if presented with invalid JSON?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-returnvalues)

Comment: And yet your screenshot indicates you're still using incorrect JSON.

Comment: @sjagr why u marked my post as duplicate ?

Comment: @Phil did, and he's quite right. Review the duplicate for your answer. The accepted answer will solve your problem. You should do some research before posting your own problem to see if others have experienced the same issue (they likely have.)

Comment: @FernandoPaiva probably because it's a duplicate.